# Restful services and messaging

Tags: java, rest, messaging

we are planning to design a system where data comes through web services and data will be processed asynchronously, i have been assigned to pick java open source technologies to do this, for web services we have decided to go with Restful services, I never worked with messaging technologies , can anyone please suggest which is the best open source technology that is available in the market that does data process asynchronously

Comment: There is no single best technology for such use-cases, you'll need to mention more about your problem statement and architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Apache CXF - see the DOCS

It has everything you want i guess

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is of processing of data asynchronously. This typically happens in following steps:

1. Receive the data and store it somewhere (in-memory or persistent location)
2. Return the *Acknowledged/Received* response  immediately.
3. Either immediately start a thread to process the data or let some scheduled thread scan the received data and process it.
4. Optionally sent acknowledge to the sending application if such an interface is available.

There is no standard library or framework in java to do this. There are individual pieces which are know to solve standard problems and combining them will be one options.

1. [Producer consumer Pattern](http://cs.gmu.edu/cne/modules/ipc/aqua/producer.html) is a typical patter which satisfies your need over there.
2. You can build a producer-consumer pattern using Java's concurrent APIs ([Here is an example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/concurrency-pattern-producer))
3. This producer consumer piece can be wrapped behind a Servlet (Or some other server side class which handles requests).
4. All in incoming request will put by the producer on the shared queue and return.
5. Consumer will pick it from the queue and process it asynchronously.
6. Another option would be to use [Asynchronous processing in in Servlet3.0](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=2).

Comment: *There is no standard library or framework in java to do this*: except JMS, of course.